# Store Swift Type in variable

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

I have a data model for a `UITableViewCell` that looks like this:

```
class SettingsContentRow {
    var title: String
    var cellType: Type // How do i do this?
    var action:((sender: UITableViewCell.Type) -> ())?

    var identifier: String {
        get { return NSStringFromClass(cellType) }
    }

    init(title: String, cellType: Type) {
        self.title = title
        self.cellType= cellType
    }
}
```

The idea is to put these in an array to facilitate building a settings view using a `UITableViewController`, and when requesting a cell i can just query the model for both the identifier and the cell `Type`. But i cannot figure out what keyword to use instead of `Type`. I have tried `Type`, `AnyClass`, `UITableViewCell.Type` and they all give rise to type assignment errors when i try to instantiate the model class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you want is `UITableViewCell.Type`. This is the type of something that is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. You can accept the type of any class using `AnyClass`, but you should usually avoid that. Most of the time, if you think you want `AnyClass`, you really want a generic.

When you try to pass your type to this init, it'll be something like:

```
SettingsContentRow("title", cellType: MyCell.self)
```

Referring to types directly is a little uncommon, so Swift requires that you be explicit by adding `.self` to it.

You may in fact want a generic here anyway. I'd probably write it this way:

```
final class SettingsContentRow<Cell: UITableViewCell> {
    typealias Action = (Cell) -> ()
    let title: String
    let action: Action?

    var identifier: String {
        get { return NSStringFromClass(Cell.self) }
    }

    init(title: String, action: Action?) {
        self.title = title
        self.action = action
    }
}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {}

let row = SettingsContentRow(title: "Title", action: { (sender: MyCell) in } )
```

Comment: Thanks that clears up a lot, just starting out with the generics stuff of Swift.